Table from PDF is converted to image when open in Microsoft word
When I am trying to open the the pdf file in Microsoft word the selectable table text is present in pdf converted to image. (Attached file and image for reference)
I have tried to open attach pdf "Test PDF_Korean.pdf" in Microsoft word the table is converted to image, I have tried to convert the pdf to word and tried to edit there it is image there as well.
My requirement is to use Microsoft office only,
Is there any way I can keep table editable when I convert pdf to docx.
I have tried to convert the pdf to word using Microsoft word but table is always converted to images, I want to check from community if some face such issue before? if yes how they fixed it.

For others landing here. A PDF would need to be MS Word suitable since "Reverse a PDF to DocX" is never guaranteed. This file should be convertible as tested by Nilesh. HOWEVER Word is struggling!
I have to suggest (as you have now already done), you raise this programming problem with MS Tech Support, since the problem sample you show works perfectly fails in multiple MS Word versions.
Fonts and structure need to be present for a half decent attempt so using your VBA or other programming methods to convert PDF to DocX is always hit and miss.  Actually here he text is perfectly viable it is word converting good text into images where they are not needed!
PDF

WORD import as only partially editable.

Answer
It is down to the human programmers intelligence (not AI) experience and skill in only using inputs that can produce a viable output ! And although a "Poor workman blames his tools" a "Good workman throws broken tools away" :-) but there is none better than MS Word for MS DocX.
The table needs the watermark removing and then the remaining areas perhaps extracted separately since they distort Words concept of tabular appearance !
Here a table retains its tabular form.
Here the selectable stays as a "Select Table".
k/g    ka  kya keo kyeo    ko  kyo ku  kyu keu ki


The editable table in pdf is converted to image in docx file it is happening for many files, (some files it is working), As you are suggesting it might be  PDF would not to be MS Word suitable, I have also put the pdf and issue on Microsoft forum

Yes, @KJ it work for conversion of pdf to docx, here problem is some of the editable table getting converted to images, after conversion to docx. Additional details of break up on  Microsoft forum
